# node.js regex splitting a string to send to another server

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm trying to split this type of string in node.js currently to send information from one server to another. I'm having trouble getting any regular expression to work considering I kind of stink at Regular Expressions in Node.js or any language at the moment. I'm trying to make it easier on myself without having a bunch of strings that replace or are split into an array. So, here's the string:

```
?name!identity@url.url
```

Is it possible to just get the name from this string without .replace() and .split()?

Comment: What do you want to extract exactly?

Comment: Basically just the name, and ignoring everything else. So it returns just name and ignores `?` `!` `identity` `@` and `url.url`. I've tried and i've been stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using matching groups:

```js
var myString = "?name!identity@url.url";
var myRegexp = /\?(.*?)\!.+?/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);

if(match)
{
  alert(match[1]);  // name
}
else
{
  alert("no match");
}
```

Comment: Well, that's what I needed thank you. I took 4 hours of trying before coming here. Thanks, credits.